# Simplest way to implement an email parser to scrape info from attachment

Tags: php, email-parsing

I get emails to my website address from a particular email address who attach an xml doc.
What's the easiest way to access the attachment so that I can scrape the data from the xml file whenever I get an email from this particular source?

Once I open the attachment I can scrape any info I need and update my database, I'm just not sure how to go about accessing the emails and opening the attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use IMAP you can use PHP's built-in imap functions.
This way, you can access the contents of the email.

Check this site for a tutorial http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap
(It will work on any IMAP account, not just Gmail).

This will help you get up to speed.
Then, when you know the basics, follow [this tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-message-body-attachments/) to learn how you can access the attachments through PHP.

Comment: Thanks, got it working.  To help others once I got the above working I just saved the xml file on my server and then used simple_html_dom to read the contents of the file.